# zipFile returns zipfile.BadZipfile: File is not a zip file

Tags: python, linux, python-zipfile

I have this Python code:

```
if '.zip' in add:
    print 'Found ' + add + ' archive. We will do nothing.'
    unZipFileName = add
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(unZipFileName) // here i got the error
    for name in z.namelist():
        outpath = unZipFileName + '/'
        z.extract(name, outpath)
```

I printed `os.path.isfile(add)` and returns True.
I use same code on Windows and it's works.
It's a problem if archive is maked on Windows and I try to unpack on Linux?

Comment: Can you extract this specific file using the `zip` command on linux? I'm thinking it might be corrupted.

Comment: @AndréLaszlo yes, i can unzip archive with command `unzip`

Comment: Can you also give the full stack trace and the value of `unZipFileName` when your program crashes?